# Should I be concerned that my pepper plants all "face" the window?

Tags: peppers, sunlight

I have peppers plants growing on my sunniest window sills, they're not massively sunny at the moment as the weathers been a bit weak recently. But the plants' leaves are quite heavily twisted towards the windows.

*Should* I be worried that the plants are quite one-sided?

If so, how would I fix this... just by rotating them?

Comment: Yes, just rotate them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if it will cause serious harm to the plant, but it will make it an uneven shape. perhaps enough for it to topple over (my outdoor peppers will topple if they're not staked). Outdoors, the fruit can get sunburn scorching with too much direct sun. I'm not sure if the glass will block enough light. If not, then this might become a problem.

Yes the simple solution is to rotate them regularly.

I had this problem with an ivy houseplant as a student. I could remember to water it - that was about it. Became quite the talking point amongst the botanists on the staircase!